# Can I mix Horizontal and vertical boxes in Java BoxLayout?

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager, boxlayout

I have to make a simple program and the `GUI` would look like this:

```````````
      ,,,,,,,,,,
     | Read    |     <---a Button
      `````````` 
name |``````````|   <---a Textfield
      ``````````
 |
 |
 a Label
```````````

My problem is how do I get the `Label` 'name' in the Vertical Box of `Button` 'Read' and text field` as the name and the text field are horizontal?

Comment: this could be possible in SpringLayout, because can be caused some issue on resize, no idea how createXxxStrut and createGlue works, mabye someone can bring the light to this potential issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please DYM???

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class BoxStructAndJComponents {

    private JLabel intro = new JLabel("The chosen name:");
    private JFrame frame;    
    private JLabel name = new JLabel("JLabel");

    public BoxStructAndJComponents() {
        frame = new JFrame("JFrame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JComponent newContentPane = createUI();
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public JPanel createUI() {
        intro = new JLabel("The chosen name:");
        intro.setLabelFor(name);
        final JButton button = new JButton("Pick a new name...");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
        });
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 10, 20));
        intro.setAlignmentX(JComponent.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        name.setAlignmentX(JComponent.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        button.setAlignmentX(JComponent.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        panel.add(intro);
        panel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(5));
        panel.add(name);
        panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(150, 10)));
        panel.add(button);
        return panel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                BoxStructAndJComponents bb = new BoxStructAndJComponents();
            }
        });
    }
}
```